# How can i access the variables passed in as_view in django

Tags: python, django, view

I am editing the existing project and i am new in django.
This is written in url file

```
url(r'^test/$', views.MyUpdate.as_view(model=models.User,
        form_class=forms.UserForm), name='user_update'),
```

Now i want to know that how can i access those variables in my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

```
Any arguments passed to as_view() will override attributes set on the class.
```

Class atrributes of UpdateView

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/

```
form_class = None   
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
initial = {}    
model = None
```

Basically you are overriding those attributes , hence they get filled automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can get the form using `self.get_form().__class__` and you should be able to get the model with `self.get_object().__class__`.

Obviously to get the form instance or the model instance just use `self.get_form()` or `self.get_object()`.

If you wanted the arguments passed to the view via the url you'd use `self.args[0]` for positional arguments and `self.kwargs['my_kwarg']` for keyword arguments.

Comment: Actually my view is like this `class MyUpdate(UpdateView):` Now in that view i have never called those `model` and `form_class` and my form is still submitting fine. Is that model and form_class being auto populated show how in update view

Comment: my bad, I just read the title and jumped in. I've updated my answer.